# SQL query for search user using combine FirstName and LastName column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to Searching in User Table should have a FIRSTNAME SECONDNAME option. 
Eg. "sa pe" should find "Sam Pethers"
another Eg. "Cris Jo" should find "Cristina Joya".

Thanks.

Comment: What is your table design? Is The FirstName and Second Name stored in separate columns or Same column?

Comment: You need to expand a little on this. Are you saying you have a table like `CREATE TABLE #S (firstname varchar(15), secondname varchar(15))`? How are values that you are provided (i.e. `sa pe`) being passed to the query?

Comment: Show your efforts: What did you try that didn't work? This query might work: select firstname, lastname from names where firstname like 'Cris%' and lastname like 'Jo%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This if you have the First Name + Last Name combined on a Single Column

```
DECLARE @Srch VARCHAR(50) ='Cris Jo'
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT MyNm = 'Sam Pethers'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MyNm = 'Cristina Joya'
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE
       WHERE 
          LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(MyNm,1,CHARINDEX(' ',MyNm)))) LIKE LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Srch,1,CHARINDEX(' ',@Srch))))+'%'
          AND
          LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(MyNm,CHARINDEX(' ',MyNm),LEN(MyNm)))) LIKE LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Srch,CHARINDEX(' ',@Srch),LEN(@Srch))))+'%'
```

And This if they are on separate Columns

```
DECLARE @Srch VARCHAR(50) ='sa pe'
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT FNm = 'Sam',LNm =  'Pethers'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT FNm = 'Cristina',LNm =  'Joya'
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE
       WHERE 
          FNm LIKE LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Srch,1,CHARINDEX(' ',@Srch))))+'%'
          AND
          LNm LIKE LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@Srch,CHARINDEX(' ',@Srch),LEN(@Srch))))+'%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable
WHERE FIRSTNAME LIKE '%Cris%' AND SECONDNAME LIKE '%Jo%'
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Your Solution is case specific and will answer only the Given Case

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh Not sure I agree with that, but the pattern `%Cris%` _is_ wrong to match a first name which starts with `Cris`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen true that!

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh the question context is to get some help by example. It is totally clear that the person who is asking it's a begginer to SQL. By this example he/she can process the query to get the desired result. 
TimBiegeleisen yes, you right, i didnt make so specific.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `LIKE` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE
    FIRSTNAME LIKE 'Cris%' AND LASTNAME LIKE 'Jo%';
```

This of course assumes that your first and last names are stored in separate columns.  And if they are not, then you should seriously consider separating them.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have two different columns

```
   SELECT * FROM 
   UserTable
   WHERE FirstName LIKE 'Sa%' AND SecondName LIKE 'Pe%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure guesswork, but:

```
CREATE TABLE #S (firstname varchar(15), secondname varchar(15));
GO
INSERT INTO #S
VALUES ('Sam','Pethers'),('Cristina','Joya');
GO

DECLARE @Search varchar(30);
SET @Search = 'sa pe';

SELECT S.*
FROM #S S
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CHARINDEX(' ', @Search))) CI(I)
WHERE S.firstname LIKE LEFT(@Search, CI.I - 1) + '%'
  AND S.secondname LIKE RIGHT(@Search, LEN(@Search) - CI.I) + '%';

GO

DROP TABLE #S;
```